# Branded organic traffic to pages having canonical tags to other domain, possible?

Tags: canonical-url

There are two sites/domains: old and new one, they both use the same structure and content. I want a new site to get all the organic traffic except branded organic traffic of the old site, that the old site should be getting.

If on the pages of the old site I'll add canonical tags with URLs to appropriate pages of the new site Will the old site continue getting its branded organic traffic? If not, what's the most possible outcome?

Comment: It's all or nothing with canonical urls.

Comment: @John Conde Will branded traffic of the old site get lost or it will go to the new site?

Comment: You will be confusing things. Canonical tags are not the same as a 301 redirect. Your original domain will lose SERP links and your new domain will gain them. Branding on your old domain will mean nothing with nothing in the SERPs. Like John says, it is one or the other and not both. Cheers!!

Comment: This makes me think to ask, Why are you doing this in the first place?? If the original domain is doing well, why try and add another? What are you *really* trying to do? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc this started as an experiment and later we saw that the new site works better for us, while the old one can continue working as it has branded organic traffic that we wanna keep.